# How to solve sequelize ./types pakage's problem. Error: Package subpath './types' is not defined by "exports" sequalize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have an error:

> Error: Package subpath './types' is not defined by "exports" connected with sequelize package.
> (Error: Package subpath './types' is not defined by "exports" in D:\Projects\pets\realtime-chat\backend\node_modules\sequelize\package.json).

Tried to solve the problem by updating all npm and node versions to the latest ones, but it was unsuccessful. I've set up the `Express` server with `socket.io` for my app and created the `User` model with sequelize using typescript.

When I try to create a new `User` with `User.create({\attributes\})`, it throws the Error mentioned above.

**server.ts**

```
import express from "express"
import { createServer } from "http"

import { Server } from "socket.io";

import apiRouter from "./routes/api.route";

import { seq } from "./models/db"

const app = express();

app.use("/api", apiRouter);
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);
});

httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log(seq.config);
  seq.authenticate();
  
  console.log("Server is started")
});
```

**User.model.ts**

```
import { DataTypes, Model, Optional } from "sequelize/types";
import { seq } from "./db";

interface UserAttributes { 
  username: string,
  password: string,
  email: string
}

type UserCreationAttributes = Optional<UserAttributes, "email">;

class User extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes> {
  declare username: string;
  declare password: string;
  declare email: string
}

User.init({
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
},
{
  sequelize: seq,
  tableName: "users"
});

export default User;
```

**My api.route.ts**

```
import express from "express"

import User from "../models/User";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/users", async () => {
  await User.create({
    password: "name",
    username: "name"
  })
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just import all these types directly from `sequelize`:

```js
import { DataTypes, Model, Optional } from "sequelize";
```